# Starting minecraft logs me out of ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, java, login-screen, minecraft

Whenever I start minecraft I can only get past the login screen. After that, the screen flashes dark, occasionally showing a `Checking battery state ...      [OK]`, and then it brings me to the login screen. I've purged and re-installed Java 7, downloaded a new minecraft jar, and updated the game itself. I'm not sure what I could do. 
Any Ideas?

Comment: try installing `openjdk-6-jre` and removing java 7. I had similar trouble a while ago with 7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a Login Loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: 12.04 is EOL. OP has not signed on for 5+ years, last time one day after posting this unanswered question. VTC as `not reproducible`.