# Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop

Tags: login, lightdm, login-screen

My Ubuntu is stuck in a login loop when trying to enter my desktop. When I login, the screen gets black and soon after that the login screen comes back.

I've read that the problem might be caused by an error depending on the graphics, here's my graphics card: ATI Radeon 7670M

Comment: Look in ~/.xsession-errors; there might be a clue there.

Comment: @CalvinWahlers Since you installed Quantal, you couldn't start the system correctly? Have you installed drivers some? Could you connect from some TTY (Ctrl+Alt+F1..F6) with any user?

Comment: no, it worked fin for I think month... But suddenly that happened

Comment: seems that I can't post an answer. I had a similar problem and after trying all workarounds mentioned here with no success, I found that my sessions where messed up in /usr/share/xsessions. Moved all files there to my /home dir (to have a copy) and tried to login using kdm (I use Kubuntu). To select kdm as login screen, I executed `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and selected kdm. With kdm you can select a previous session or a default one. This was the way to go.

Comment: I have same graphics card ATI Radeon HD 7500/7600 M. I also got into bootloop yesterday. Reason : I did a restore using `sbackup`, everything worked but after restart I got into login loop. For me nothing mentioned in answers worked so i did a fresh system install. I commented my part so that any link between both can help community. Things i restored were folders : home, etc,usr,var.

Comment: Just as a note that I had this same issue but was caused by a disk that was full. I logged into shell, ran some du commands and realized it was due to a process I left running on my computer for a long period of time. I deleted some of the 50+ GB log files and all was restored

Comment: I had the same problem and it was simple. My Virtualbox Lubuntu 16.04 had run out of disk space. I cleared some space and - Shazam! 
Back again.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to answer, but what worked for me was following instructions [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/335285/how-to-change-proprietary-video-driver-using-the-command-line). In short do `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`, and then `sudo apt-get install` the recommended driver.

Comment: The most likely cause of this issue is syntax errors in `~/.profile` as implied by [Dan Cundiff's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/246858/21665). Much more likely than all the other suggestions. **You fuck up your .profile, and you can't log in next time.** That simple.

Comment: after trying many ways, I found that the problem was because of installing indicator-multiload . With purging it my problem resolved. I can not answer so I write my experience as comment!!

Comment: Guys, I managed to fix the exact problem. Background, my machine (desktop) runs 16.04 with latest patches up until June 2018 12Gb Ram.  Having tried most solutions offered, I found the problem was missing /usr/bin from the PATH.  The way to find it, if you do have this problem is:  When you get your login screen drop to the terminal by issuing  ctrl+alt+f1 then issue any command IE vim  if you get an error "The command could not be located because /usr/bin is not included...  Then you have the same problem.  Edit the file /etc/environment  add :/usr/bin:  save it / exit /reboot.

Comment: I just had this error on my freshly installed vbox Debian. I tried everything mentoined below in the accepted answer, but didn't worked. I logged into recovery mode and I noticed that a zero-fill file (which I created to minimize the disk space) didn't deleted by the last command of my script... I think it's worth to note that non-available disk space can also create similar issue, where you think there's some problem with lightdm.

Comment: Happened to me today, Ubuntu 18.04. Curisouly, just restarting the machine did the trick. Go figure.

Comment: Happened to me today, Ubuntu 18.04. If none of the answers here work, look at `/var/log/syslog`and check for any error that might relate to something you did recently. My issue was an error related to `flatpak`, which I've installed the day before but ended up not needing it. After uninstalling it, everything went back to normal.

Comment: I have tried all the answers, but I still have problem with login.

Comment: There is one more possible reason . If you mess up the /etc/environment file then also it can happen. To fix . do ctrl+alt_+F3 and login to session. check if you can run any shell command. if not then that's the problem.

Comment: In my case it was a NVIDIA problem and this helped: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux
Thanks to `ubuntu-drivers devices` I could see that I needed to install recommended driver so `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` fixed it

Comment: I think I have a situation that isn't mentioned elsewhere on this page. I had upgraded to 20.04 and found that logging into GNOME failed (and Wayland worked). I had to run `ampgpu-pro-uninstall` to get rid of the old drivers and the standard ones built in seem to work fine. Can't do a proper answer - not enough rep.

Comment: Wow. This question is from 2012, and I'm having this problem on a fresh install of the last version in 2020. It's seems that Canonical spends all of its resources designing fancy buttons. What a joke.

Comment: For me this problem appeared after I enabled the `Automatic Login` option.. To fix this I opened the command prompt (Ctrl+Alt+F7), created a guest user via `sudo adduser myguest` and logged in with it to disable the `Automatic Login` option...

Comment: In my case the issue was in `~/.profile` including `~/.zshrc`. I don't know if I made this mistake or if it happened after I had installed Oh My Zsh (I think so)

Comment: Try switching to `Ubuntu on Wayland` on the login screen, it helped in my case

Comment: @felipsmartins boy, this might be the reason it fails for me 2 :-O I had this issue on all my distro installation in the last 4 months, Ubuntu, Debian & Fedora. All had the same issue, nobody else in my neighbourhood so hard to tell what the reason was/is.

Comment: @jaques-sam glad this worked for you

Comment: Happened to me too on Ubuntu 18.04. I looked at `/var/log/syslog/` and found error message `JS Error: TypeError: malformed UTF-8 character sequence at offset.........org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js......` I deleted in my home directory the folder `gnome-shell` - the path is `home/<your user>/.local/share/gnome-shell`. This solved my login loop and I was able to login as normal.

Answer (score 462, accepted):

Did you end up here after running `sudo startx`? Nevertheless:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and login into the shell.

Now run `ls -lA`. If you see the line

```
-rw-------  1 root root   53 Nov 29 10:19 .Xauthority
```

then you need to do `chown username:username .Xauthority` and try logging in (you may also need to do the same for for `.ICEauthority`).

Else, do `ls -ld /tmp`. Check for the first 10 letters in the left: they should read exactly so: `drwxrwxrwt`.

```
drwxrwxrwt 15 root root 4096 Nov 30 04:17 /tmp
```

Else, you need to do `sudo chmod a+wt /tmp` and check again.

If not both, I'd recommend you either

1. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`
2. or uninstall, reinstall it.

Now press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> until you reach the login screen again, and restart.

Comment: I've same problem, chown username:username .Xauthority helped. But, anyone has an explanation?

Comment: @ts01 I think my problem was "gdm-session-worker crashed with SIGSEGV in act_user_is_loaded()"

Comment: I did delete the /tmp folder manually I probably was not a good idea for gdm.

Comment: I actually even had to remove my .Xauthority for things to work. For some reasons, none of the above solved my problem.

Comment: both deleting /tmp and .Xauthority will cause Ubuntu to recreate those folders/files with right permission on next bootup. This is an (unintended) way of doing what i suggested first.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. Couldn't the devs think of something simple like popping up "Permission denied while attempting to edit /home/username/.Xauthority. Ensure username has read/write permissions."? This could have saved the 41000 people who have viewed this question so far some huge headaches.

Comment: +1 - Although I had to do this for both .Xauthority and .ICEauthority

Comment: Once I fixed this problem by reinstalling ``xserver-xorg``. The second time Gnome had vanished somehow and I had to reinstall ``gnome-session-fallback``.

Comment: I've had the same problem, but it was my fault, because I modified /etc/environment to add some environment variables and I made a mistake.

By following @SiddharthaRT's instructions, I was able to solve the problem.

You know:
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/vi /etc/environment

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The chown on .Xauthority fixed that.
What can cause that?

Comment: I had to chown .Xauthority, .ICEauthority, and .gvfs. This was caused by me running sudo startx from an ssh session, because for some yet undetermined reason, X keeps shutting down

Comment: This happened after installing a VNC server. The fix worked great!

Comment: Wohoo! Setting the permissions on `/tmp` saved my butt.

Comment: +1. In my case .Xauthority was owned by root. In other users' folders, .Xauthority was owned by them. No idea what altered that - I switched from openbox to afterstep and when i logged out, i could get back in

Comment: @Nacht DON'T run sudo with startx. Using sudo to run startx is exactly how the permissions of the Xauthority file can get screwed up like this. Run startx as your normal user and it should work. If it doesn't, check the ownership of the .Xauthority file to make sure it's not owned by root again.

Comment: The login loop is unfortunately a recurring issue with Ubuntu 14.04; whenever I bump into it I end up at this answer just to check once again that it solves nothing. No idea why it is accepted, since it only addresses a narrow case of file permissions. In most cases the log in loop is caused by bugs with Unity that are not solvable by the user.

Comment: > "anyone has an explanation"... well, by running `sudo startx`. >  "DON'T run sudo with startx... Run startx as your normal user", well if that had worked to begin with we wouldn't be here, now would we?.

Comment: At least there should be a warning about running startx via sudo.

Comment: Else, do ls -ld /tmp. Check for the first 10 letters in the left: they should read exactly so: drwxrwxrwt. What should I do after the text reads exactly so?

Comment: As most of the people in this comment section, I too (thankfully?) ended up here after running `sudo startx`.

Comment: Changing owner for .Xauthority worked also for me on Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop

Comment: i never ran "sudo startx", hell i never typed "startx" either... and i ended up here too :( Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: What if I can't use Ctrl+Alt+F* because my host also is Ubuntu and it goes switching to another terminal?

Comment: ctrl+alt+f3 and `sudo apt-get purge lightdm` `sudo apt-get install lightdm` solved problem. Also what is the difference between ctrl+alt+f1 and ctrl+alt+f3?

Comment: @mrgloom No difference; ctrl+alt+f1 through f6 are six CLIs that work exactly the same way.

Comment: .Xauthority file owner shall not be root.

Comment: A crashed teamviewer session (daemon running as root) caused this problem for me. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: sudo chmod a+wt /tmp   :  This doesn't seem to change the letters. I currently stuck have dxwxr-xr-x. I'm going crazy with this loop!

Comment: When i run ls -lA i do get `-rw-------` but what should it look like once i apply the fix?

Comment: Also happened on my raspberry.

Comment: I had to search for this answer waaay to long.

Comment: @AbidH.Mujtaba Reinstalling `xserver-xorg` worked for me too, with the caveat that initially it seemed that the installation was unsuccessful (came out with an error that `xserver-xorg-core` was Broken). However, running `startx` now works, and the previous issues are fixed. I don't know what to make of this.

Comment: Actually, after the above I ended up with this related problem (Ubuntu crashing to login screen when trying to open settings): https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049288/ubuntu-18-04-opening-system-setting-logs-me-out
But the first answer successfully fixed that too. Seems to be an issue with the xorg driver.

Comment: It happened to me because I was feeling adventurous, and did a sudo chown -rf 1000:1000 /home/users

Comment: I ran into this issue(possibly) after installing tightvncserver and running `sudo tightvncserver`. I removed `.Xauthority` file after reading this answer and the login worked normally after that.

Comment: In my case the issue was in `~/.profile` including `~/.zshrc`. I don't know if I made this mistake or if it happened after I had installed Oh My Zsh (I think so)

Answer (score 80):

I had this and after looking at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` I found out that it's a Nvidia problem (there was a line saying `Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0`).

I realized I have Nvidia drivers from official website which are not really stable and tested (so I've read and also experienced in the past).

The solution here was to install package `nvidia-current` from Ubuntu repos; it is an awfully outdated version, but it's tested properly at least. Its installer is quite capable too and it uninstalled successfully my hack-installed unstable version from Nvidia website.

**TL;DR**, just try logging into the shell (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or whatever F between <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>F6</kbd>) and type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-367
```

If it succeeds, reboot.

```
sudo reboot
```

If you're lucky enough, problem solved, you should be able to login to Unity.

**UPDATE**

Please note that sometimes `nvidia-current` might install the wrong driver. In that case, search the latest compatible driver for your video card and install it. For example, on Ubuntu 16.04, `nvidia-current` points to the version: 304.131-0ubuntu3. This might be incompatible with your graphics card; therefore, search with `sudo apt-cache search nvidia-[0-9]+$` for the package you need, and install it.

Comment: I often have the login loop issue after installing updates. For those who want to use the Nvidia drivers from the website, you need to reinstall them.
As you said: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  <kbd>F1</kbd>
Login
`cat .xsession-errors` if you have this message `Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0` it means there is a GPU driver issue.
Download the nvidia drivers
`sudo service lightdm stop` `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-xxx.xx.run` `sudo reboot` And it should be fine

Comment: I had the same issue. I had to remove all the previously installed drivers; then install "nvidia-361" (right now it's the latest version for ubuntu), run `sudo update-initramfs -u`, then reboot. unfortunately nvidia-current was installing "nvidia-304" that probably isn't compatible with my video card. But thanks for leading me to the right solution! :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this helped to fix login Issue in 14.04.

Comment: I installed some weird nvidia driver while trying to get the cuda libraries running on my system. doing `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` and then getting `nvidia-current` fixed it (finally after 2 hours). Thanks a ton!

Comment: I got this problem today when trying to reboot without a keyboard just to experiment with logging in using the onscreen keyboard.  Even after rebooting with a keyboard attached I was still stuck in the loop.  I had some days before installed the `nvidia-current`,  so today I tried `sudo apt-get install nvidia-367` and that seems to have fixed it.  Maybe I should have removed or purged previous drivers but I didn't, seems to have done that by itself.

Comment: Same for me, but I had to use the [solution suggested in this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/836504/323990).

Comment: I didn't listen and installed 'nvidia-375' which didn't help. Following instructions and installing  'nvidia-367' worked ;) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me by replacing the nvidia driver version to the supported one by my card. So it is better to check first for the right driver version for your system before writing down the version number here.

Comment: For me this was the correct answer.

Comment: I'm getting permission denied when trying to run this:  /var/log/Xorg.0.log

Comment: @Moondra: that is a log, why would you try to run it? A/w, sudo is needed for operations (read, write) on these files, I believe (can't test it now)

Comment: This did not work for me.

`ace@ace-hole ~ $ sudo apt install nvidia-367` | `[sudo] password for user: ` | `Reading package lists... Done` | `Building dependency tree` | `Reading state information... Done` | `Package nvidia-367 is not available, but is referred to by another package.` | `This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or` | `is only available from another source` | `E: Package 'nvidia-367' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 70):

I encountered this exact problem and none of the suggested fixes above worked for me. After almost giving up I looked at the `.xsession-errors` and noticed I had a typo in my `.profile` (I had an extra `}` in the file after I edited it earlier in the day).

That was causing the login loop. It might be another place to look if the other suggested fixes don't work for you.

Comment: My situation was very similar. I had recently added a run function for running commands multiple times in my .profile and that function, though it worked as advertised, seems to have been the cause of my problem. Commenting it out fixed it.

Comment: This worked for me.  My PC lost power during an electrical storm and some how I ended up with a extraneous line at the end of my .profile. No clue how it got there.  Anyway, I'd say the general solution should just be to check .xsession-errors and see what it says.

Comment: This is a good one! I hit the same lightdm login loop problem, spent 30 mins troubelshooting with no luck (tried all possible workaround I can find). Turned out to be a syntax error in `~/.profile` caused by `rbenv`.

Comment: This solved my problem - failing line in ~/.profile

Comment: +1 - Thanks for mentioning `.xsession-errors`

Comment: This worked for me.  I had recently installed an incompatible program and once the references were removed from the .profile, I was able to log in again.

Comment: @TerryWang, Same here. I have no idea why though. I don't remember adding that line, so I don't know why it suddenly broke my entire Xorg session. Another reason to hate Ruby...

Comment: After hours of debugging the login loop, it ultimately was an error in my `~/.profile`. Thank you +1

Comment: I got the login loop for one user, and for that user I found that a script invoked from the .profile had a `set -u`, and the ~\.xession-errors showed XKB_IN_USE: unbound variable. Removing the `set -u` allowed the login to complete. I did not find which script used XKB_IN_USE , but it was not in the same file as mentioned by BUGID  1452539.

Comment: I think it is fairly good question to ask: did the user edit the `~\.profile` before reboot? I didn't have an `.xsession-errors` at all, but I did forgot a closing bracket in my `~/.profile`. Maybe you should adapt the answer to emphasize that **the most likely culprit is a syntax error in ~/.profile**, and besides, to check for `.xsession-errors` to further the evidence.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this. I spent half the day upgrading graphics drivers and running through kernel logs and then this was the solution.

Comment: I also moved unnecessary test from ~/.profile and then "source ~/.profile" -- solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you sooooooooooooooooooooooo much, exact mistake

Answer (score 53):

I had a nearly identical problem a few months ago. Switching into a console from the LightDM login screen (Ctrl-Alt-F1), logging in with administrative username and password, and entering the following commands resolved the issue:

```
sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.backup
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Comment: ,Thanks I just type the second command It solved my problem but what this command will do will you plz elaborate

Comment: This command renames ".Xauthority", which is a file that stores credentials used for authentication of X sessions (basically a cookie), to ".Xauthority.backup". Renaming this file causes xauth to create a new ".Xauthority" file, thereby re-authenticating.

Comment: BRILLIANT. can't thank you enough - worked first time.

Comment: I had the this issue 3 times with Ubuntu, Debian and Fedora. This is a gnome issue!!! And we’re now 2023… sigh. So for me this worked, but it doesn’t create a new .Xauthority file after login, why? The file is just nog needed and SHOULD NOT INFLUENCE THE STARTUP BEHAVIOUR :-$

Answer (score 39):

My **home folder was full** :-( `df -h` will give you this answer I had to connect through ssh made some space and worked like a flower

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, login as user, free up some space and restart your X server! mostely `sudo service sddm restart`

Comment: yeah,mine too, my home folder was almost full... 800GB from 1TB... i tried all of other solutions,didnt work... so i transferred 300GB of my files too external hard disk... and it worked ... thanks Philippe:)

Comment: For me it was issue with not enough disk space because of huge log files.
Pressed Ctrl+Alt+F3 to log into the shell + emptied the log files ==> Now I can log normally

Comment: thanks, helped me well! just in case you guys aint want to delete some file you might need try `sudo apt-get -y autoremove && sudo apt-get -y clean`

Comment: Thanks @Philippe Gacgoud, In my case chromium-browser generated a lot of .pma files at /home/user/.config/chromium/BrowserMetrics, after removing these files I got everything running again.

Answer (score 21):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>. You should be given an unix-style login prompt, so enter your username and password there. From there you should be given a *shell* (a program that allows you to enter commands, sort of like windows' `cmd.exe`). Enter these commands and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (or <kbd>Return</kbd>) after writing each one (you will have to enter your password when it shows something like `[sudo] password for USERNAME`. Note that the password will not show when you are typing it!):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -y install fglrx
```

Then reboot your computer using this command:

```
sudo reboot
```

See if this works :)

---

If this does not work, try going back to the 3rd terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>), login, and enter this command (pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after you have typed it):

```
sudo apt-get -y install lxdm
```

This will show a DOS-like dialog after a bit. If `lxdm` is not selected, select it by using the <kbd>UP</kbd> and <kbd>DOWN</kbd> arrow keys, and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to accept that selection. Then reboot using the same command as before (`sudo reboot`).

---

If this *still* doesn't work, go back to the 3rd terminal (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>), login, and enter this command (same procedure):

```
sudo apt-get -y install lubuntu-desktop
```

This will install a much lighter desktop environment which *should* work for now (should enable you to login and use your computer). Once that is done, reboot (`sudo reboot`), and when you are confronted with the login page, select the `Lubuntu` environment instead of `Ubuntu`.

Comment: This will not work. X is running he is crashing post login (i think).

Comment: I know, that is because Unity crashes. Probably because 3D does not work. The LXDM solution is for using as little 3D resources as possible so that more resources are freed for Unity.

Comment: I see, could work, I have no idea if lightdm uses "3D" or not.

Comment: I think it does... or at least it's _seriously_ heavyweight.

Comment: If lightdm uses 3D then shouldn't it trigger the crash, not after it hands control to unity?

Comment: Well just trying to learn myself. Once thing we can agree on is that unity is crashing.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but lightdm is a _display manager_, so it takes care of displaying everything (I think). If it uses 3D, things will be displayed using 3D (at least in my experience).

Comment: Anyways, if it doesn't affect, I added the `lubuntu` option so that  he can at least access his desktop. Not optimal, but it's better than nothing :)

Comment: but when I use my pc I also want to work with a desktop environment I like :) It's installing now, let's hope that Lubuntu can fix it :)

Comment: @CalvinWahlers, don't worry, I will work with you to fix 3D stuff (that includes unity), but we first need something working to do so :)

Comment: ok, that's really nice :)

Comment: @CalvinWahlers does lubuntu work? And no problem :D

Comment: no ist doesn't... I've already used gdm, lightdm and lxdm, without any success

Comment: Even  when selecting Lubuntu instead of Ubuntu (the session, not the display manager)?

Comment: down because there's a simpler solution.

Comment: The first part fixed it for me. It also removed some nvidia drivers which were probably causing the issue in the first place and then also fixed my graphics to take on full 2560x1080 resolution. Nice one :)

Comment: Simply doing these two things fixed this for me:  sudo apt-get update  followed by sudo apt-get -f -y dist-upgrade   the -f option was required for me due to some conflicts.

Answer (score 20):

Faced the same problem today.

The cause was a bit strange to me. `xubuntu-desktop` was removed, so was `ubuntu-desktop`. LightDM exited with no error message. Tried lxdm and when I tried to login, it popped up a message saying Xubuntu could not be found.

Reinstalled `xubuntu-desktop` and it's fixed now. Think `apt-get autoremove` removed the package.

Comment: this autoremove does stupid things. This tool shold never be released (or it needs to be much more tested and improved) as it is so time consuming to fix this irritating problems! Nothing is more frustrating than keep looping in a login screen. luckly ubuntu has other options and I logged via Gnome Metacity session, the only one that worked...

Answer (score 13):

You might be having problems with LightDM, the login manager that comes in Ubuntu by default.  In 12.04 it used to do the same problem you are describing.

You can install GDM, an alternative login manager, to get around this:

At the login screen, press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to go to the terminal.  Don't be afraid!  Just log in here with your username and password.

Then, type `sudo apt-get install gdm`.  Let it install and type `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` and follow the prompts to set it as your login manager.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to get back to the login screen which should now look different.  Does logging in work?  If it does, your problem is solved!

If it doesn't, go back to the fullscreen terminal (again, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) and run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` to set LightDM as you login manager again.  Now you know that this is a  problem with your graphics drivers for sure.

Comment: ok, I think I'm not quite such a noob, I know how to enter a terminal there and how to log in :) And I already have installed gdm: doesn't work. lightdm: doesn't work. lxdm: doesn't work...

Comment: OK.  You definitely have a graphics problem then; LightDM can sometimes mirror the problems you're describing (it might help if you said how long the delay is).  Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: Delay means the time between having entered an appearing again?

Comment: Right.  It is like a couple seconds, or more like 30, etc.  I can't help you with graphics issues but I'm sure there is someone here that can.  Good luck!

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 this method gets you a blank screen in place of the login screen.

Answer (score 11):

Your desktop environment is failing to start (it sounds like). I would start by tring to log in as a different user.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> then login

`sudo adduser testing`

Once the user has been added <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd> and try to log in as testing. If you can log in as testing then your unity/gnome configuration is borked and should be reset. [This Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration) covers it. I prefer to `mv ~/.config ~/.config.old`.

Comment: I can't log in as testing...

Comment: You could have bad libs, try MiJyn's answer. If you can gain access via lubuntu then you have a library issue.

Comment: This page gets a lot of traffic, so modern update: `adduser testing` will not create a Home directory, which will also cause this login loop (at least in Ubuntu 20). You need `adduser -m testing`

Answer (score 11):

This is not a direct answer to your case but its more of a general solution to login loops.

The problem could be as simple as a wrong command put into the .profile file in the home directory. (Since that file get loaded on logon)

To see if that is really the case, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  <kbd>F1</kbd>, and login. Checking the .xsession-errors file in your home directory

```
~/.xsession-errors
```

This should give some clues about some problematic command.

Answer (score 10):

I've pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and logged into the shell.
Afterwards with this command:

```
chown username:username .Xauthority
```

Where `username` is my login name, I've solved the problem.

Comment: Thankyou this worked great! I got this error after opening startx with sudo! Cheers!

Answer (score 9):

Yes I caused a Login Loop on my main Ubuntu 12.10 user and the fix was simple.

Background:
Ubuntu 12.10 is installed in VirtualBox running on Windows 7 and uses Unity.

Cause:
From the Desktop I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> into terminal mode and then tried to run 'startx' (I was trying to help a friend over the phone late at night...but this was a stupid thing to do). A new blank Unity desktop appeared and everything hung...

**Problem:**

Forcing VirtualBox to close and then rebooting Ubuntu I got to the login screen but kept looping back to this same screen everytime after entering the password. No errors were displayed. I could login as Guest but I had no Sudo rights and thus no control...
However once logged in as Guest I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and got to a terminal login.

I entered my main user name and password and logged in with command mode. Logout took me back to CLI login and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> took me back to Guest desktop. So my account still worked. I then added a test user and gave them sudo rights. From the Unity login I could login and logout Test user with no problem. So Unity still worked.

Fix:
So my main account was still accessable via CLI and Unity was working for all other accounts. This indicated a configuation problem on my main account. I followed the advice of SiddharthaRT at the top of this post and did `chown username:username .Xauthority`. This fixed my problem. Thanks !!

Comment: I'm facing the same problem today in 14.04.02 but unfortunately I disabled the guest account.  My user and root passwords are not being accepted in any terminal I've tried.  Any suggestions? I already went ahead and installed 12.04 alongside thinking I might be able to access my files on the 14.04 side, but no luck

Comment: I have now run into this problem after trying to fix my R instance. Richard, did you manage to fix your problem?

Answer (score 9):

I only had to change the permissions of my home folder:

```
sudo chmod 755 /home/<username>
```

This can be done by logging in, into a terminal, using your username and password in a shell using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>.

Comment: After trying all, I just ended up that "let me check my user's home directory permission", and found the problem, then I was scrolling down and I see you already posted this as an answer  :  )

Comment: this was my login loop cause as well your answer fixed it +1; I checked /tmp, ctrl+alt+f1-7 did not work for me for some reason, but I could get to root via the grub menu at boot, creating a new user also did not work - it had the loop in the new user too; tried to switch to gdm3, even worse, the screen went black at boot so went back to lightdm; disk was not full; could not check .Xauthority as the home was encrypted;tried openbox xfce all the same; how the home directory permissions were changed to r-x------ not sure, but the loop started after the netbook shut itself down due to low battery

Answer (score 9):

**Proprietary Driver Issues**

[MoKSB State](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1571691)

I was able to log in to `TTY` using `ctrl+alt+F1`, but had no internet access seeing as the driver is proprietary as well.

No Xorg issues were apparent.

I decided to remove the packages when I recieved the `MokSB failed` message telling me that it could NOT change the secure boot settings. The notable part is that it prompted me for a password even though it failed.

[Secure Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765509/login-broken-after-15-10-16-04-lts-upgrade-related-to-nvidia-driver)

**Caution: Do NOT just blindly remove your drivers!**

A good **test to see if it is a Proprietary Driver issue** is to turn OFF Secure Boot and boot Ubuntu and attempt to login. If logging in works, then you now know what you're issue is.

[Broadcom Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) and [Nvidia Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics)

I removed nvidia packages

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
```

and then I removed the broadcom packages

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and rebooted.

I attempted to login again and success!

I saw my desktop!

I rebooted again. 
logged in again and everything was set to default.

- I rebooted into BIOS
- turned off secure boot (not recommended, need a better solution)
- booted up ubuntu using grub
- logged in and installed the downloaded *.deb file for my wifi driver
- installed it using Software Center
- and rebooted.

I followed the same procedure for my nvidia drivers seeing as the default video drivers are awful on my card.

**Turning Secure Boot On Again**

If I turn on Secure Boot again, I see the same issue. Since the drivers are NOT signed, it's not a true Secure Boot and I get locked out.

Personally, I find this to be a very bogus (and annoying) issue.

**Alternative Solution?**

The most feasible solution I saw was *customizing the kernel* seeing as I can't simply leave Secure Boot off and turn it On and then Off when I switch OS's. Again, it's just annoying.

**UPDATE on Jan 4 2017**

According to this [article](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-Features-From-2016), the Linux Kernel >= 4.6 now officially supports

> GeForce GTX 900 series accelerated support in conjunction with signed
>   firmware images.

This should resolve the secure boot issue caused by using the unsigned firmware images.

Comment: This fixed the login problem as in I could login again, but WARNING `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*` somehow (???) also manages to try and reinstall mysql. This seems crazy, but I replicated the behavior. Thankfully it did not delete my files, but when it produced an error it did manage to change configurations. This makes no sense to me, but I replicated the behavior and it asked me to give it a new mysql root password again so this indeed occurs. The graphics issue is super annonying and also strikes me as bogus issue made up by Ubuntu, but on the solution GOOD GRIEF YOU HAVE BEEN WARNED.

Comment: I had the same issue, and turning off Secure Boot seemed to be the only way to fix it.

Comment: Couldn't ubuntu log in with low resolution driver and tell user that faced a problem with the driver instead of getting looping ? It is the expected of a really intelligent software... maybe here is a feature request.

Answer (score 9):

I have been through this problem multiple times and it has been a different issue each time. One of the following issues could have caused your problem and you could use the command line interface by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (Replace F1 with F2,F3.... if your tty1 is occupied) to try the following solutions

### NVIDIA drivers missing or broken?

1. Run `nvidia-smi` to access the NVIDIA system management interface. The output should be something of this sort.

> ```
> Mon Sep 17 14:58:26 2018       
> +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
> | NVIDIA-SMI 390.87                 Driver Version: 390.87                    | 
> |-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+ 
> | GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC | 
> | Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. | 
> |===============================+======================+======================| 
> |   0  GeForce GT 720      Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 N/A |               N/A    | 
> | 19%   35C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    543MiB /   980MiB |     N/A Default      |
> +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
>
> +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
> | Processes:                                                       GPU Memory | 
> |  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                        Usage           | 
> |=============================================================================| 
> |    0                    Not Supported                                       |
> +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> ```

If you're not able to access it, there is probably some issue with your graphic drivers.

2. In that case, you should be able to find out the name of your graphics card using `lspci | grep VGA`.
3. You can find out the compatible drivers for your graphics card using the [link](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us).
4. (Try without this stepand maybe then with this step if there was no success). Remove the existing broken drivers using `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`.
5. Install the drivers using

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers`

   `sudo apt-get update`

   `sudo apt-get install nvidia-390` (Or whatever the compatible driver is for your graphics card)
6. Try a restart using `systemctl reboot -i` and hope your login loop is fixed.

### Is your HOME your HOME?

1. Check the owner of your home directory using `ls -l /home`
2. If you don not own your home directory, change it using `sudo chown $USER:$USER $HOME`
3. Try a restart using systemctl reboot -i and hope your login loop is fixed.

### Do you own your .Xauthority?

1. Check the owner of your home directory using `ls -l ~/.Xauthority`
2. If you don't own your .Xauthority, change it using `sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/.Xauthority`
3. If you do, move your .Xauthority file using `sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.bak`
4. Try a restart using systemctl reboot -i and hope your login loop is fixed.
5. You might need to do the same thing on .ICEauthority.

### Is your /tmp right?

1. Run `ls -ld /tmp` and make sure the permissions are exactly `drwxrwxrwt`. The output should be of this sort

`drwxrwxrwt 27 root root 36864 Sep 17 17:15 /tmp`

2. If not, run `sudo chmod a+wt /tmp`
3. Try a restart using systemctl reboot -i and hope your login loop is fixed.

### Maybe lightdm is your problem?

1. Reconfigure your display manager using `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and try out other display managers (gdm3,lightdm,) that are available. Maybe this will you give you enough clues to move forward.
2. If none of them help,try installing sddm using `sudo apt-get install sddm`
    for one final try. reconfigure display to sddm.

If none of the above solutions worked, you can try re-installing ubuntu.

P.S: This is a compilation of answers from the sources I refered to, some from this post as well.

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER $HOME
```

was the problem for me.

I had set up a home partition with:

```
sudo mkdir /home/$USER
```

but forgot to `chown` it.

Comment: This worked for me like charm :)

Answer (score 5):

I found my `/tmp` file permission settings were not correct. It had permissions for root only.

This was my own mistake. I forgot that a day earlier, I deleted the `/tmp` folder with `sudo` rights and after recreated the folder again with `sudo mkdir tmp`.
Big mistake. I created a /tmp folder with root permissions only.

In the `~/.Xsession-errors` file I could see that x11 was not able to write a file in `/tmp`. After execute these commands from the root account (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>) in welcome screen and use the problem account credentials to login) I solved the problem:

```
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
sudo chown root:root /tmp
```

After these, I was able to login to Unity again with the normal account again.
So if you have, what looks like a `.Xauthority` problem, you could try this if nothing else works.

See [this thread on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=868941)

Answer (score 5):

I got the login loop in connection with an update from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04.  With gdm I had error messages in ~/.cache/gdm/session.log with entries such as `/etc/gdm/Xsession: line 33: mktemp: command not found` and after `sudo aptitude purge gdm` with lightdm I got several similar error messages in  `~/.xsession-errors`, e.g., `usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 24: mktemp: command not found`.

I tried several things. What I believe did eventually resolve the problem for me was this:

I moved my configuration files `.profile`, `.bashrc` and `.pam_environment` to other names and then I managed to login. I suspect that there is a problem in one of them.

Comment: After installing Ubuntu 18.04 and adding my usual .bashrc, I ran into this problem. Removing the .bashrc fixed it. I assume there was an error that didn't surface in 16.04, or maybe Unity didn't execute the .bashrc on GUI login, but GNOME does.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem after a clean install of Ubuntu 12.10 (but reusing my existing home partition). I tried all of the other answers, but none worked. But I found the clue to my specific problem in the file .xsession-errors in my home directory.

This is how I solved it in my case:

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open a virtual terminal. Then login with username and password.
2. Open the file `~/.xsession-errors` if it exists (type `cat ~/.xsession-errors`). In my case, this file contained one single line with an error message:

   > /usr/sbin/lightdm-session: 27: .: Can't open /usr/bin/byobu-launch
3. Now `byobu` is a command line tool that I use and I have no idea how that ended up in a system file since this was right after a clean install. Byobu is not installed by default, so that might explain the error as it looks for a file (`/usr/bin/byobu-launch`) that doesn't exist. So in my case I had to install `byobu` to fix the problem:

   > sudo apt-get install byobu
4. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to go back to the login screen, and login worked fine now.

Of course in your case you might find a different error message in .xsession-errors, which requires a different solution.

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar issue where I could log in on the terminal but not on the desktop, my wallpaper from the profile was loaded during login, but after a few seconds it jumped back to the login screen. I checked all file permissions as suggested, they were fine. I tried without a separate home partition and was able to log in to the desktop. After that I checked the settings for the LUKS encrypted home partition, which were also fine (though there were some error messages on the terminal, telling me that the encrypted volume could not be mounted, because it was already mounted).

Then I looked into dmesg, found BTRFS errors related to the filesystem on the LUKS encrypted home partition (yep, I'm mixing LUKS and BTRFS), tried to actually write to the filesystem and found that it gave me I/O errors. So I had to repair the filesystem or create a new one and restore from backup.

Long story short: Look at dmesg and actually try to write to the filesystem that seems to be writable.

Answer (score 4):

## 20.04 and above:

#### Opening a console

To open a console, you can press  <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + f5</kbd>  or boot into grub recovery mode.

### Method #1 Removing Old Configuration files.

As System 76 support says in their [article](https://support.system76.com/articles/freezing-behavior/), you can remove the old configuration files to fix this issue:

1. Add a new user

```
sudo adduser test
```

2. log in as the new user (`test`)
3. If the login worked without any issues then there are problems with the configuration files of the main user.
4. Backup/remove the old configuration files:

```
mv ~/.config ~/.config.old
mv ~/.local ~/.local.old
mv ~/.cache ~/.cache.old
mv ~/.nvidia-settings-rc ~/.nvidia-settings-rc.old
mv ~/.nv ~/.nv.old
sudo reboot
```

5. If the configuration files are automatically generated then leave this step:

```
sudo mkdir ~/.config
sudo mkdir ~/.local
sudo mkdir ~/.cache
sudo mkdir ~/.nv
sudo mkdir ~/.nvidia-settings-rc
sudo reboot
```

Now try logging in with the regular user.

---

### Method #2 Changing permissions of .Xauthority

1. Identify the permissions of the file by running (run this in your home directory):

```
ls -lah | grep -i Xauthority
```

2. You should see the file listed with the permissions first, followed by the username and group that own it. If you see “root” listed there, you’ve found the source of the problem.
3. Give proper permissions:

```
sudo chown username:username .Xauthority
```

*change "username" with your username.*

---

### Removing Gnome shell extensions

Sometimes a corrupted gnome-shell extension can also cause this issue. Removing the extensions will help:

```
sudo rm -r ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/*
```

---

### Resetting gnome

Sometimes, there are problems with configuration files, in that case resetting gnome and its applications will help:

```
sudo dconf reset -f /
```

### Installing correct Nvidia drivers

1. First, remove all the Nvidia drivers by running:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
```

2. Auto install the recommended drivers:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

3. Install the specific drivers for your device:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
# identify the drivers needed 

sudo apt install nvidia<version>
```

4. Try using system76 drivers (optional):

```
sudo touch /etc/apt/preferences.d/system76-apt-preferences
echo "Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-system76-dev-stable
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-system76-dev-pre-stable
Pin-Priority: 1001" >> /etc/apt/preferences.d/system76-apt-preferences
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:system76-dev/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install system76-driver-nvidia
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

---

### Disabling AMD Radeon Drivers

On newer versions of Ubuntu AMD, GPU chips are not well supported, so sometimes it is causing the issue. Turning it off would help:

```
sudo echo blacklist radeon >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
sudo shutdown -r now
```

---

### Reinstalling display manager

Sometimes the display manager needs some troubleshooting, reinstall it:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop gdm3 gnome-shell
```

After that run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

Select the option `gdm` and press enter.

---

### Changing display managers

You can install a new display manager by the following commands:

```bsh
sudo apt install lightdm
### If you want sddm 
sudo apt install sddm
```

Then run:

```bsh
sudo dpkg-reconfigure <display manager name> # example lightdm
```

---

**Thanks to System76 support, for letting me use some information (method #1, method #3, and method #4) for letting me use some information from their [article](https://support.system76.com/)**.

Comment: I believe `adduser test` should be `adduser -m test` . I could not login without a home directory in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I don't have enough AskUbuntu rep to answer this question, so I'll just say it here--recreating my user with -m allowed me to login (Ubuntu 20.04).

Comment: Followed the  display manager steps and it worked, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This could also be because of a special combination of settings:

- Encrypted `/home/$USER`
- `$USER` in `nopasswdlogin` group

`lightdm` will try to log you in, but can't access any files so you get the described symptoms.

To fix this, remove `$USER` from the group:

```
sudo gpasswd -d $USER nopasswdlogin
```

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same problem and the cause in my case was that I tried to add something to the `/etc/environment` file and whatever I added seemed to not want me to log in after I restarted.

### Solution:

When at the login screen press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>. Login with admin username and password and edit the `/etc/environment` file and remove what changes you made to it.

In the terminal, you can run the following command use `nano` to edit the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to save the file. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.

Once you have edited and saved the file, simply hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to go back to the GUI login screen and you should be able to log on.

Answer (score 3):

I had to deal with the same problem.
Unfortunately in my case it was not resolved by simply changing permissions so my contribution will be to try to create a guide from the simple to the more complex steps. Hopefully your uses will be resolved with the simple ones.

Note: replace `<username>` with your username.

Assumptions: `Nvidia Graphic Card`, `lightdm`

---

**Access To Terminal**

To open a new terminal simply use (and then login with your credentials):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

**Check the owned/group/permissions of your home directory files**

```
cd ~<username>
ls -lah
```

**Fix the owner and group of `.Xauthority` and /tmp**

```
chown <username>:<username> .Xauthority
sudo chmod a+wt /tmp
```

**Check if there is still a problem by restarting lightdm**

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

---

**Reconfigure lightdm**

```
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
sudo service lightdm restart
```

---

**If you wish to see possible errors from the system**

```
tail -n 50 /var/log/Xorg.0.log # if you want to see the last 50 errors
tail -f /var/log/Xorg.0.log    # if you want to be able to see all new errors live
```

Relevant log files:

```
/var/log/Xorg.0.log
/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
```

---

As a last resort, which is what I did, reinstall the graphic card drivers.
`Nvidia` simply does not work nice with `Ubuntu`.

Answer (score 3):

I had to remove NVIDIA drivers to get in, as in (replace nvidia-current with nvidia-340 or whatever your number is).

[Revert back to Nouveau drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264532/revert-back-to-nouveau-drivers)

Then I had a buggy UNITY frame. I had to follow the steps showed here to fix them:

https://askubuntu.com/a/290376/275142

Comment: this fixed it for me. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me when I switched off the computer while it was still finishing upgrading to the latest kernel images. I did CTRL-ALT F1, logged in, then `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and let it finish to setup.

After rebooting, I was able to login into the destkop again.

Answer (score 3):

Solved using these commands:

```
 sudo apt purge gdm3
 sudo reboot
 sudo apt install gdm3
 sudo service gdm start
```

Answer (score 2):

Change to another login screen.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to open a terminal.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to go back to the graphic mode.

Type `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`

In a graphic screen, select gdm and OK.

Type `sudo reboot`

Comment: I don't think thiss will work, he is having problems after gdm/lightdm

Comment: No, the lightDM loop does actually happen like this (although it depends on the length of the black screen)

Comment: until now, nothing really helps :( i selected gdm but now there's only the ubuntu 12.10 wallpaper, nothing else

Comment: Probably I should add that the last time I used Ubuntu firefox told me to restart it... it crashed. LibreOffice also did. Then I rebootet and since that moment yesterday it doesn't work.

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 19.10. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just in case changing the access privileges for the files `.Xauthority` and `.IDEauthority` with the `chown` command did not work for you:

This solution applies to those who besides having had to change access privileges for the above mentioned files cannot use commands as they used to, i.e. the shell does not find the commands. (This is the reason, why the login command cannot be executed either.)

Type `echo $SHELL` into your terminal. If you get back `/bin/bash`, use `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin` to temporarily be able to use commands.

Then open your `.profile` file, located in your home directory `~`, i.e. `/home/yourusername` with `sudo gedit ~/.profile` and add the missing paths to `PATH`, so that it looks like this:

`PATH=/usr/local:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin`

Now reboot your system so that the changes to the environmental variable PATH take effect.

(If commands are not recognized by your shell, you could also use the equivalent paths to the executables of the commands, e.g., instead of `sudo gedit ~/.profile` type `/usr/bin/sudo  /usr/bin/gedit ~/.profile`. The shell tells you the directory to use, i.e. `command` not found, but the command your are trying to use can be found in `/path/to/command's/directory` - could be any of the paths you see above.)

Comment: This solution actually worked for me, the issue was I had made some changes in "/etc/environment/" file that caused login loop. But none of my commands were working even in safe mode, so your trick to temporarily enabling commands worked and I was able to access my system again. Thanks and +1 for the solution

Answer (score 2):

May you are affected by [Bug #1240336](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-desktop-privileges/+bug/1240336) where different permissions are gone after release upgrade.

**Other side effects**

- no guest login
- Synaptic not starting from menu

I get login to work when I put the user into the `video` group **or** after running `sudo chmod a+rw /dev/dri/*` in a terminal.

But:

- no sound
- Logout from user menu not working
- running `/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1`
  gives: polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:5805): polkit-gnome-1-WARNING **: Unable to determine the session we are in: No session for pid 5805

**Solution**

Run `sudo pam-auth-update --force` in terminal.
This solved the described problems in my cases.

Answer (score 2):

For me configuration of some packages was off, so running (after `ctrl` + `alt` + `F3`):

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

fixed the problem.

Comment: This can happen also if you do a Ubuntu version upgrade, and there is an interactive prompt that dpkg misses during non-interactive install.

Answer (score 2):

If you recently installed `indicator-multiload`, uninstall it.

This problem happened to me after I installed `indicator-multiload`, so uninstalling it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after I upgraded to 12.10.Then I came here from Google. I created another user and I could login.

As I don't use Unity, I uninstalled lighdm. After reboot, I could login. You can try that.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have been experiencing the very same problem a couple of times every week and have tried most of solutions given here but the only way I can log back in is by restarting lightdm.

sudo service lightdm restart.

The funny thing is that even after I restrat lightdm, it does not log in on the first attempt but only on my second attempt even though I am entering the right password. I realised this a few weeks ago and I have verified this a few times, making sure that I am not accidentally keying in my password wrong. I am now certain that it does not log me in 
the first time after restarting lightdm but only on the second attempt!

Comment: Today I got a clue about my problem. I have an external monitor connected to my laptop. When I got into the login loop I decided to somehow get it working with restarting lightdm. From a bug report in launchpad I got an idea that it could be due to some issue in recognising my external monitor. So, I disconnected the monitor, dropped to tty1 and back and the login worked the first time! Not the second time like when I restarted lightdm. This is better but there has to be a solution which does not require this.

Answer (score 1):

If the other questions do not lead to a solution, my suggestion is to try to follow these steps:

1. Login in character mode with a VC (Virtual Console). That is, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd> and your username/password login. Let's call this user `original`.
2. Create a new user. You can use [for example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70236/how-can-i-create-an-administrator-user-from-the-command-line):

   ```
   adduser newuser --group sudo
   ```

   to add a new administrative user (that is, a user that can do `sudo`).
3. Try to login as `newuser`. If it works, you now that the problem is in the specific setup of `original` user. Otherwise, stop reading here --- the problem is at system level and you'll probably need to reinstall something of the graphic stack.
4. Now you can try to search what happened. Compare hidden files in `~original` and `~newuser` and try to find mismatches. Especially you should search for files not owned by you:

   ```
   find . \! -user original
   ```

   and files that are not writable to you (there will be more of them, especially in caches):

   ```
   find . \! -perm -u=w
   ```
5. You can move suspicious files to a backup (`sudo mv whatever whatever-backup`) and try to login again.
6. Files in `/tmp` and `/var` that can be sensible to this problem should be deleted by a reboot --- but sometime there is some remnant over there, too.

As a last resort, you can backup the important info of `original` (not all the home dir! or you'll propagate the problem), and delete and recreate it, although it is better to be able to find *where* the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was caused by wrong permissions on my home directory.

**1:** Boot from a live media (or different linux distro installed on the same system) and open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>

**2:** Make a temporary mount point and Mount the partition that contains your /home (in my case it was /dev/sda6)

`sudo mkdir /mnt/sda6`
`sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt/sda6`

**3:** check permissions

`sudo ls - la /mount/sda6/`

you should see an entry *username*` where *username* is your username

From this point forward we will use the *username* tvbox (change this to your username)

You should see something like this:

`drwxr-x--- 67 tvbox tvbox   12288 May  1 07:00 tvbox`

This indicates that tvbox is a directory and the owner has the required read, write an execute permissions.

**4:** correct permissions if incorrect.

If the above is incorrect in any way we need to correct it.

If data was moved by root you will see root root rather than tvbox tvbox (owners name owners group) This could be referred to as the "root cause" ;-)

To fix this issue the command `sudo chown -R tvbox:tvbox /mount/sda6/tvbox

If somehow the other permissions aren't right you will need to modify them with `sudo chmod +rwx tvbox` adding read write and execute permissions.(the execute bit on a directory allows you to traverse it.)

**5:** reboot the problem OS

**6:** login

If this doesn't resolve your problem refer to the many other quality answers here.

Comment: It seems that Elder Geek's issue was caused by a user ID mismatch.This fixed it for me 

      sudo chown -R NEWUSER:NEWUSER *
      sudo chown -R NEWUSER:NEWUSER .*   # to include hidden files and directories

For more details see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230434/ubuntu-20-04-can-t-login-after-upgrade/1234771#1234771

Answer (score 1):

For me following worked.
Type `ctrl + alt + F1` and login with your username at command prompt.

```
user@dell$ ls -l ~/.ICEauthority
-rw------- root root 3668 May 28 09:28 /home/user/.ICEauthority
user@dell$ sudo chmod 777 ~/.ICEauthority
password:
user@dell$ ls -l ~/.ICEauthority
-rwxrwxrwx root root 3668 May 28 09:28 /home/user/.ICEauthority
```

`ctrl + alt + F7` and login worked.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this issue on a Xenial installed on a usb key, mounted on a HD-less laptop, running unity and gnome-flashback.
Tried about every workaround in here without success, then remembered that some days ago, while in chroot and using qemu, if I choose gnome-flashback-compiz I got the issue while with unity I didn't. Tried with gnome-flashback-metacity and it worked.

In this case too, it doesn't work with gnome-flashback-compiz but with gnome-flashback-metacity and with unity it worked.

Silvia

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my user folder somehow got `chown`'ed by root!  The answer lies in `.Xauthority` and other files in your home folder; if user config data can't be opened read/write, lightdm will fail.

I simply <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>, logged in, then `sudo chown /home/<userdir>`, then `sudo service lightdm restart` (may not be necessary), and then I was able to get back in.

Some diagnostic messages would be more useful, but such is life with free software.

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding Gnome Users:**

I tried all of these optionals to no avail. Likely due to using Gnome as my preferred UI.

After looking at [Sooth's Answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/248943/229716) I was able to get it to login with the ubuntu and xubuntu GUI, so his post helped a spark in my brain.

I didn't see anything related to Gnome, so I looked up some instections and followed this guide from [OMG Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/05/install-gnome-3-20-ubuntu-16-04-lts) for Gnome 3.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.

I had Gnome working flawlessly so I have no clue what went wrong one day. It's a bit of a download and upgrades but **this worked for me with Gnome** and I'm happy without the login loop of death!

Answer (score 1):

I found another way to cause a login loop not covered by any of these answers, yay me!

I had a script to set up my dual monitors that was referenced in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` as a `session-setup-script`.  When I went to a single monitor config, I deleted the script, but did not remove the reference.  Next time I booted up - login loop.

Examining the logfile in `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` I found an explicit error message telling me the script was not found and therefore lightdm failed to start.  Commenting out the reference in `lightdm.conf` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

After reading [James answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/120215/678565) , I realized I had changed the user password by logging in as root. I knew the old password, so I logged in as root again ( to login as root press `ctrl+alt+F3` give the username as root and and enter your root password) and changed the password for that user to old one by below command

`passwd <username>`

Now change the password to old one , press `ctrl+alt+F7` and login normally.
This solution works only if you have encrypted home directory issue and incase you had changed password using root.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue recently. Ubuntu made some updates and i got this login-loop that seemed to be related to lightdm.

I finally managed to solve the issue after trying several things.

I suspect amdgpu to be the reason of failure but because i dont know for sure, i am going to post everything, that i tried:

Taken from my original question on askubuntu: [See here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top)

1. uninstall amdgpu-pro (`amdgpu-pro-uninstall`)
2. install the open source driver ([see here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AMDGPU-Driver)). I also installed all those *hwe* packages.
3. reinstall and reconfigure lightdm, ubuntu-dektop, unity

At this point - after rebooting - my keyboard would not respond anymore, so i booted into recovery mode and selected the option to repair broken packages, which worked and i could use my keyboard again.

Unfortunately the login still would not work. Additionally i added my user to the lightdm group, but i doubt that is of any importance.

Then i found other similar issues and tried the following steps:

```
# as root
add-apt-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
reboot
```

Still no success so far, so i decieded to try another upgrade method

```
# as root
apt full-upgrade
reboot
```

And then i was able to login again.

**My personal conclusion**

It seems the problem exists within the amdgpu driver and ubuntu will not be able to install a working driver unless you add the ppa mentioned above. It says to work only with Ubuntu 18.04 but i tried it anyway and it worked *for now*.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem on multiple RPIs (version 2B and 3). Solution:

- check the .xsession-errors file: `cat ~/.xsession-errors`. Mine showed:

> Xsession: X session started for pi at ****
>
> Xsession: unable to start X session --- no "/home/pi/.xsession" file, no 
>   "/home/pi/.Xsession" file, no session managers, no window managers, and no 
>   terminal emulators found; aborting.

- to solve this reinstall the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all \
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev libx11-6 x11-common \
x11-utils x11-xkb-utils x11-xserver-utils xterm lightdm openbox
```

Source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=154190

*fyi:
I used the RPIs before with auto-login and non-gui mode. Thus, I reinstalled lightdm and ended up at the login loop problem after switching to auto-login GUI mode (raspi-config).*

Answer (score 1):

GNOME-Shell extensions installed to user's profile were apparently causing the login-loop in case of Bionic Beaver installation here.
User is able to again successfully login to its graphical environment not until removal of all of GNOME-Shell extensions installed to user profile. Found then removed from Bash had been `ext-helper@amanda.darkdna.net` and `workspace-grid@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com`.

I believe to had found that track by examining systemd journal, there was also a signal in web addressing Gnome shell extensions in this or close context.

Problems started to occur after installation of security and basic updates in calender week #3 of 2019. Actually no reconfiguration at system level was conducted by user that time.

Now two system-level GNOME-extensions are left because no way was found to uninstall them too. However these are set to disabled. Extensions' main switch is also put to OFF. Maybe middle or long term I will try to use extensions again, however by progressing with caution and in small steps.

Consequently none of hints found here could help as the underlying points were OK, e.g. ~/.XAuthority, ~/.ICEAuthority, /tmp directory, Nvidia stack.
lightdm-based approach was undesired as in this case Ubuntu 18.04 is used which does not use lightdm as default.
It is installation running in VmWare-hypervisor so the emulated graphic card is not from Nvidia. Those hints could not be applied too nor help.
I was also unable to find in ~/xsession-errors directive hints.

I found Rmano's approach interesting and applied that which in consequence uncovered few other interesting points, these will be raised in new Questions.
Also Rmano's hint contributed to success in this case. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for giving an account of what you experienced ... but I don't see how it answers the original question.

Comment: My Question raised one week ago or so was put by other members to duplicate of this one. You see zero commonalities?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot log in, the disk/partition of your home folder might be full.

To find out if your disk/partition is full: press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>, login and type `df`. You get information on the used disk space.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure nobody except someone with an extreme case of the issue will see this, but if you do... maybe this will help!  :)

Adding to the current answers - and building off of them to a large extent, I have once or twice had the problem that files *other* than `.Xauthority` are owned by root for some reason.  This can create login loops, problems with secondary monitors, and a host of other issues.  To locate suspect files, run:

```
user@hostname:~$ find -user root
```

From there, you kind of have to fish around in the output and see if you can't locate something that looks unusual.

As a side note, it also shows if `.Xauthority` is owned by root...

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this was caused by a newly installed software through the Software center (or whatever its called) called Brightness Control (Xrandr). So I logged into Ubuntu using Unity from the logging window and then I opened up the Software Center to uninstall it. After rebooting I could log into Ubuntu (Gnome).

Answer (score 1):

There is another possible cause for this problem not covered in the other answers:

**If your homefolder is encrypted and you changed the user password without changing the encryption password.**

In this case when you login, your password will not be the same as the encryption password and your home folder cannot be loaded. As a result, your .Xauthority file will not be able to be loaded, and you won't even find it if you try to as suggested in @SiddharthaRT's and many others' answers.

*(As a hint if you don't remember if your home folder was encrypted, if you do `ls -lA` you should see some files with "encrypt" in their name and a folder called .Private if your home folder was encrypted.)*

You have two options:

1. The easiest is to reinstate your old user password, using

   ```
   sudo passwd user
   ```

   where user is your username. Then you'll be able to login as normal again. However, if you changed your user password you probably have a reason for this, so the 2nd option is better.
2. Rewrap (i.e. change) your encryption password, as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33730/will-changing-password-re-encrypt-my-home-directory). Basically, to do this (assuming you have kept your new user password), mount your encrypted home folder as follows

   ```
   ecryptfs-mount-private
   ```

   and then set the encryption password to the new password with

   ```
   ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase ~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
   ```

   Then everyting should be mounted as normal again.

Answer (score 0):

I got into the login loop by running the software updater for 18.04 on Jan 30 2019.  It was very hard to get into terminal mode per <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd>, succeeding typically only after a number of reboots.  Getting into terminal mode per <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> became reliable only after installing lightdm and switching to that as suggested in the popular answer above.  The other standard recipes (check ownership of .Xauthority and .ICEauthority and permissions of /tmp) were in order and mucking with the nvidia driver didn't help.  After much googling I found Khalil Laleh's suggestion at [Ubuntu 18.04 Login window loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086367/ubuntu-18-04-login-window-loop) to check your gnome extensions. Bingo! In my case Zakkak's workspace grid = 'workspace-grid@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com' in directory ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions needed to be removed to make Ubuntu finally start up, and then reinstallation from https://extensions.gnome.org restored my workspace layout.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem on both my office linux installation and home machine. I installed a program which required compilation and the executable file was in the bin directory of the program's folder. I exported the PATH, but on booting the normal /bin /usr/bin ... was replaced by my mistake, so the path to bin was only my programs/bin folder. Hence it went to login loop

Once I removed my added path, it started booting normally.

Another user -xpioneer had pointed  out the problem.
I am just reproducing below--

"There is one more possible reason . If you mess up the /etc/environment file then also it can happen. To fix . do ctrl+alt_+F3 and login to session. check if you can run any shell command. if not then that's the problem. – "
xpioneer
Dec 7, 2019 at 4:28

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I looked at `~/.xsession-errors` and found the problem was actually at `~/.profile` with a missing binary which wasn't needed anymore.

I deleted the line and restarted lightdm with `sudo systemctl restart lightdm.service` and it worked.